# Google Maps HTML icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to create HTML based icons, instead of using the images.

Example I have seen is,

http://housing.co.in/bangalore/rent/flats-near=hebbal%20kempapura:13.047757:77.594895:3000

Answer (score 2):

You can use the utility libary for maps v3.

https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

richmarker reference:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html

example:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html