# Use HTML element instead of icon for map marker with gmap3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, font-awesome, jquery-gmap3, glyphicons

I'm creating a map that will show devices of different types.  Through out my web application, each device type has it's own unique icon.  These are all done using fontawesome graphics.  I would like the map "icons" to match, without having to screencap all of them and lose the ability to cleanly scale them as necessary.

It's very easy to use a custom image, as in the documentation example below, but does anyone know if I can use some HTML instead?

```
  marker:{
    values:[
      {latLng:[48.8620722, 2.352047], data:"Paris !"},
      {address:varAddress1, data:varData1},
      {address:varAddress2, data:varData2, options:{icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png"}}
    ],
  ...
```

**update**: The possible duplicate mentioned uses PHP to extract icons from the font-awesome SVG.  This is very restrictive.  I would really like to be able to use an HTML element if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Icon Fonts as Markers in Google Maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Oh very nice.  Not sure why I didn't find that one.  Thanks.

Comment: Wait, that library uses PHP files to extract the SVG.  That's a show stopper, unfortunately :(

Besides that, I'd honestly like something more flexible, like HTML instead of an extracted SVG from a specific library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps HTML icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632593/google-maps-html-icons)

Comment: Found a question that is a duplicate and has an answer which solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"richMarkers" from Google is a much better solution.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is remarkably easy!  You replace "marker" with "overlay" which allows you to do the following:

```
    overlay:{
        values: [
            { latLng: [38.55240, -90.41710], data: "PRINTER01", options: { content: "<div>Whatever you want here!</div>" }  },
            { address: "1234 E. Main Street, Springfield USA", data: "SERVER01", options: { content: "<div><i class='icon-reorder'></i></div>" } }
        ],
```